# when will google wave step out of preview release?

Tags: google-wave

So that wave robots can be hosted with any web host.

Note: For this developer preview release, all Wave robots must be implemented as Google App Engine applications. A future release will introduce the ability to host robots with any web host, at any web address.

Comment: Wave to me just sounds like a car-crash between rich-email/web-pages/image boards/wikis and god-knows what else. Good at everything, great for nothing?

Comment: It looks better then email, or any commenting system I have ever seen on blogs/forums. Whether or not it will change the world completely depends on how many people choose to use it instead of rolling their own mediocre solutions for their sites.

Answer (score 2):

It has been announced that the plan is to "start extending the Google Wave preview beyond developers on September 30th".

http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2009/07/google-wave-updates-from-todays.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about timelines - such as when it'll be an "open beta" instead of "invitation beta" - but I'm hoping to port the Robot API from Java to .NET, so that when you *can* host robots outside AppEngine, you'll be able to do so in ASP.NET.

I've got an [empty Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/wave-robot-net-client/) set up for this already, and hope to start porting the Java source code next week, with any luck. You may well be able to start *writing* robots in .NET before you can start to actually see them in action :) (I'll be able to test internally though - it's not going to be an entirely blind port!) Watch the project to get updates...

Comment: It will be able to when the restriction has been lifted in general, yes. Until then only I (and other Googlers) will be able to test it, in a more lenient internal environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything has been announced yet. Google is notoriously shady about release planning of their products, so it will probably be "when it's ready".